# VLC Plugin Uri with umlauts does not Play

Tags: c#, activex, vlc, mediaelement

I have written a programm to watch some media from a network drive. I switched from MediaElement to VLC Active X Plugin which works a lot better (does not have any codec problems).

The only left over problem is with paths that contain special characters.

Simplyfied example: C:\Mâñrchen.avi (originially Märchen.avi)

```
//currently looks like this
var uri = new Uri(urlFullPath, UriKind.Absolute);
var convertedURI = uri.AbsoluteUri;
axVLCPlugin21.playlist.clear();
axVLCPlugin21.playlist.add(convertedURI); //expected parameter type is string (only worked with Uri)
axVLCPlugin21.playlist.play();
```

I do not get an exception, it just does not start playing.

Comment: I deleted my answer, you should probably add the comment for my answer in your question. I will up vote and hope this question had more attention. Good luck!

Comment: @mybirthname suggested to use convertedURI.Normalize(enumType) but all of them did not work :/